# No characters from foreign languages while using ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internationalization, html-helper, actionlink

When I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Collection.Name)
```

Everything seems to be ok, but when I use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Collection.Name) + "", "Index", new { })
```

There are no all foreign characters. First one displays "żółć", second - "`ż&#243;łć`". Why is that? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), `Html.DisplayFor` is intended to

> Return HTML markup for each property in the object that is
>   represented by the Expression expression.

But your `ActionLink` is simply expecting a regular `string` to display as the link text.

You better use `DisplayNameFor()` instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Collection.Name).ToString(), "Index", new { })
```

See [DisplayNameFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833706%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)